# CentOS 5.x - `inittab` failing on `rc.d` calls

Tags: linux, centos, init

I have several servers that run some python scripts at the end of the `inittab`. I have one server which is having issues and the scripts weren't running. With troubleshooting, I found that if I moved the python scripts calls before the `rc.d` calls that they launch. If I don't then they never get called.

The rc.d calls:

```
l0:0:wait:/etc/rc.d/rc 0
l1:1:wait:/etc/rc.d/rc 1
l2:2:wait:/etc/rc.d/rc 2
l3:3:wait:/etc/rc.d/rc 3
l4:4:wait:/etc/rc.d/rc 4
l5:5:wait:/etc/rc.d/rc 5
l6:6:wait:/etc/rc.d/rc 6
```

This matches the other `inittab` files on the other servers, but I assume something went bunk in one of those scripts. I'm curious where I can look to get more information on what is stopping or causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It will be noisy but you can add a "set -x" inside of the "rc" script and then you'll hopefully see what is going on when things fail.  Just remember to take it out when done.  Unless you like all of the noise (and larger than normal log files).

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: OP was wanting to know where things fail... .I beg to differ this will show the OP where it is failing.